# WPF control is not refreshed properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue with refresh for a normal text block. My code is as follows:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread newt = new Thread(Tick);
        newt.Start();
    }

    void Tick()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            textBlock1.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(

          delegate()
          {
              textBlock1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }
            ));
        }
    }
```

With the application running, the monitor goes to sleep mode at `12:55:55`. When I reactivate the monitor at `1:02`, I noticed that the value is updated each second, however as the hour has no ten's unit now, it is left aligned and the unit's place of the seconds of `12:55:55` is not refreshed.

So, it shows the value as: `1:02:555`. The last 5 is from the `12:55:55` before the monitor went to sleep.

The control is only refreshed after I minimize and maximize the window in which case it shows the time correctly properly refreshed.

It's a display driver issue with NVidia FX 1800. Has anyone ran into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the dispatcher priority to a lower one, this will make sure your text box is refreshed.

Comment: I used DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle. And it did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use textBox.InvalidateVisual(). It forces the textbox to rerender. But it has performance impacts as the control should know itself very exact what part should get rerendered

Comment: No..InValidateVisual had no effect! :(

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the UI thread to sleep for a 1 second before returning. You should not put the UI thread to sleep. I believe you intended for your background thread to sleep for 1 second, if so then you'd need to do:

```
void Tick()
{
    while (true)
    {
        textBlock1.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(

      delegate()
      {
          textBlock1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
      }
        ));

          // Executed on background thread, not UI thread
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```